# How to change position of legend in levelplot of rasterVis in R?

Tags: r

By default legend is plot right side and I want to change it to bottom of plot.

```
levelplot(CHL1, xlim=c(30,130), ylim=c(-20,30),
          xlab="", ylab="", margin=FALSE, col.regions=pal,
          at=seq_along(brks), colorkey=ckey) +
    layer(sp.polygons(msk, fill='black', col='transparent'))
```

Comment: This is not related to GIS directly and should be asked on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `colorkey=list(space="bottom")`:

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, colorkey=list(space="bottom"))
```

[image: plot]